# Question about Serial communication of Vex V5 brain

Tags: ros2, tutorial, serial, vex

I'm currently developing serial communication for the Vex V5 brain. In the process, I came across the solution you provided on GitHub, which can be found here: https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/591 The solution is fantastic, but I still have two general questions that I can't quite grasp.

1. Do the ports in the constructor statement `V5RS485(int readPortNum = 19, int writePortNum = 20, int baud = 115200)` correspond to the smart port number on the Vex brain? If so, that would be great because I can use a smart cable instead of RS485 and conduct experimental communication between the brains.
2. Is there another solution that directly uses a micro USB?

Thank you so much!